# Can you recover the Mnemonic or secret keys from a Polkadot.js JSON backup?

Tags: polkadot, wallet

I want to add my polkadot account to the Trust wallet. There is no option to use the json. Is there a way to recover the private keys from the raw json backup?

Comment: https://support.polkadot.network/support/search/solutions?term=json might help here if, and only if, you have the password to unlock (decrypt) that json file. Likely need to import tp a supporting wallet to export a seed (if it's possible)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can recover the private key but not the mnemonic seed because it uses a one-way algorithm.

I don't feel familiar with the keystone to private key.

But I got an idea. Maybe you could use this method https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/sp_application_crypto/sr25519/struct.Pair.html#method.from_entropy to get the private key.

But I don't know how to deal with the keystone file.

```json
{
    "encoded": "...",
    "encoding": {
        "content": [
            "pkcs8",
            "sr25519"
        ],
        "type": [
            "scrypt",
            "xsalsa20-poly1305"
        ],
        "version": "3"
    },
    "address": "...",
    "meta": {
        "genesisHash": "...",
        "isHardware": false,
        "name": "1",
        "tags": [],
        "whenCreated": 1670590064209
    }
}
```

It looks like that we need to decode the `encoded` field to get the raw `entropy` first.

---

I finally figured out how this works.

The private key is called `MiniSecretkey` in the `schnorrkel` library. The `Secretkey` is an extension of `MiniSecretkey` with some hash functions. The encrypted version of the `Secretkey` is stored in the JSON file's `encoding` section, making it impossible to recover the private key from the JSON file.

I have added a decrypt feature to Subalfred. You can use it to recover the `Secretkey`. However, please note that there is no wallet support for importing a 64-byte `Secretkey`. You may need to write your own program using these types of keys (which can be easily done with the `schnorrkel` library).

Check latest Subalfred at https://github.com/hack-ink/subalfred/releases/latest.

Comment: Trying to use this module, but due to my limted rust knowledge I am facing problem. How can I use that code? I tried to install the crate with "cargo install sp_application_crypto", but it cant find the crate. Do I need to install another crate or is it some other local error?

Comment: Create a new cargo project. Edit the `Cargo.toml`'s dependencies field. Add `sp-core = "7.0.0"`.

Answer (score 1):

No. Both the Polkadot browser extension and Polkadot-JS UI only show your mnemonic seed once: during the initial creation of your account.

If you miss taking note of it, or if you misplaced your seed, there is no way to view it again at a later stage. While you can always restore your account from your JSON file, you won't be able to see your mnemonic seed again.

You can create a new account storing the mnemonic words and restore the account using JSON file in order to transfer all the funds to the new account.

Comment: How about the private key? It should be possible to somehow recover it from the json. Do you know a way?

Comment: You can get the KeyPair and with that sign: https://polkadot.js.org/docs/keyring/start/basics#keypair-types But not the private key directly

Comment: Doesnt "keyPair" mean the private and public key?

Comment: The private Key is on it, but you can not "extract" the raw private key. Check this answer where is explained in more detail: https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/3286/2762