# Getting Mnemonic/Seed Phrase from JSON backups

Tags: polkadot-js, polkadot-js-extension, subkey

I have a password-protected digital backup of an account using the JSON file from the Polkadot.JS extension.

How do I get the mnemonic/seed phrase from this file so that I can back it up on paper? This account is staking and I would prefer NOT to move the funds.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you recover the Mnemonic or secret keys from a Polkadot.js JSON backup?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/6288/can-you-recover-the-mnemonic-or-secret-keys-from-a-polkadot-js-json-backup)

Comment: @AurevoirXavier looks like a step in the right direction, as a paper backup of a private key would suffice. However, as a non-coder who is experienced in command line and compiling polkadot-sdk, how exactly would I do this? All I see in the linked comment is a piece of code, not a method to recover the private key.

Comment: I have updated my answer at that post. Please check.